# Rigged through Blender (Rigify) and Errors in Unity

Tags: unity, animation, blender, rigging

I am working on a Unity scene and as the 3D model is missing the bones, I ended up going to Blender for the [rigging](https://docs.blender.org/manual/es/2.79/rigging/index.html).

For that, I followed the [procedure that Unity suggests](https://docs.unity3d.com/560/Documentation/Manual/BlenderAndRigify.html) by using the add-on Rigify. I was also following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pAhbO7U1ID8), which was really helpful.

[image: Rig obtained]

After exporting from Blender (in .fbx) and importing it on Unity, I went through the configurations ([as @vcard suggested here](https://portal.babelx3d.net/content/tutorial-using-makehuman-characters-unity))

In the "Rig" section, I pressed the button "Configure" (to configure the Avatar Definitions) and came across an error "Character is not in T pose".

[image: Character not on T pose]

I solved this one quite fast by accessing the menu "Pose" (in the Inspector) and then "Enforce T Pose".

[image: Character on T pose]

After that, back in the scene, I came across the following error on the Inspector:

> Invalid Avatar Rig Configuration: Missing or invalid transform:
>   Required human bone 'Head' not found.

[image: Error warning]

I went straight to the configurations and decided to add the specific bones to the Head that appeared on the inspector (in the Avatar Definitions configurator). With that, I came found out that the problem is really the organization where there were placed by Rigify.

[image: Errors]

Any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I didn't find the ideal order for the structure that allowed Unity to recognize the existence of the bones 'head' and 'neck' (that were present), I ended up using another platform: [**Mixamo**](https://www.mixamo.com/) ([check here how to upload and rig 3D characters](https://helpx.adobe.com/au/creative-cloud/help/mixamo-rigging-animation.html)).

> I strongly recommend **Mixamo** as it is online, free and super simple to
>   use.

---

### Process

1. Start by uploading the character:

[image: Upload Character]

2. Press "Next".
3. Place the markers. If your character is symmetric, before positioning the markers, activate "Use Symmetry" (which simplifies even more the task).

[image: Mixamo - Place Makers]

That's it. This is the Skeleton view in the review process:
[image: Mixamo - Review - Skeleton View]

Then I downloaded it in the format "FBX for Unity" and imported in Unity.

Now the Santa can finally close its arms:

[image: Character with Mixamo Animation in Unity]